# Unable to boot Ubuntu 16.04 after not being able to update software

Tags: 16.04, boot, updates, boot-repair

Recently I got a normal "please update your software" message, entered my admin password, and proceeded to update as usual. The installer tried to install the updates and failed to do so.
I then tried via Terminal using apt-get install + update + upgrade.

I then tried to reboot and now when I try to boot up, it stays frozen on the loading screen. I tried to create a liverepair thumb drive and installed Boot Repair. It threw an error and here's the PasteBin.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/B8HC4Ntf28/

Can someone please help?

Comment: Two things. 1) You've formatted sdb thumbdrive as FAT16, when it is recommended you format with FAT32. 2) You've used an ISO as a boot file. The error message says `sdb2 failed to mount`. Although you can boot from an ISO it's better practice to extract it. So I'd move the ISO to another disk, reformat the sdb thumbdrive, then extract contents of ISO to the sdb and try booting it again.

Comment: Hey Paul, thanks for your input. Unfortunately that didn't solve my issue and sdb2 is an external hard drive that I never plan on booting up with so don't feel the need to format it at this time. That being said, I noticed an external hard drive was unplugged when I went to boot up that time. Is it possible a drive listed in /etc/fstab threw everything off?

Comment: Also, I created another live disk, formatting it correctly this time, and got this new error: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sWjCvqFjhr/